# Google Calendar Events Watch error 401 Unauthorized with service account

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am trying to watch multiple calendars to get push notifications for any changes:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch

I keep getting the error:

**Request failed with status code 401**

I am using a service account, which I have given access to each calendar.

My config is:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "eventapi-219011",
  "private_key_id": "5ac83bf728fc9f3f635cec8096170573620dd388",
  "private_key": "xxx",
  "client_email": "googlecalendarservice@eventapi-219011.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "111757078202416067272",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/googlecalendarservice%40eventapi-219011.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I have verified the domain. Here is my code, any ideas how I can get access?

```
let { google } = require("googleapis");

let privatekey = require("../config.json");
let axios = require("axios");

let ids = [];
let promises = [];

async function main() {

        const client = new google.auth.JWT(
            privatekey.client_email,
            null,
            privatekey.private_key,
            [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
            ]
        );

        const token = await client.authorize();


        let config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                Authorization: token.token_type + " " + token.access_token
            },
            type: "web_hook",
            address: "https:/rguc-calendars.firebaseapp.com/notifications"
        };

        axios
            .post(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/rguc.co.uk_5hbugn8f7a4j3g7p6im1r1s1co@group.calendar.google.com/events/watch",
                config
            )
            .then(function(response) {
            //  console.log("latest" + response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            })
}

main();
```

I can get a list of calendars fine using:

```
const res = await client.request('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList');
```

But not a `watch`, here are my credentials, which should I use?

```
API key 1
Oct 10, 2018
AIzaSyBkAEZGoQwB0f-Kmq4mCCzm93422up8oQw

OAuth 2.0 client IDs
Web client 1    
793554220141-91kh36o41rq2b337d1fcl50lvbqesl36.apps.googleusercontent.com

Service account keys
5ac83bf728fc9f3f635cec8096170573620dd388 GoogleCalendarService
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for for a service account to work it must be pre-authorized.  Take the service account email address and share the calendar with the service account like you would any other user.

This should also give you access to the push notifications for the calendar.

If that doesn't work make sure that the service account was the one who created the initial watch request.

**To many scopes**

calendar gives you fill access to a users calendar there is no reason to ask for readonly as well just use the one you need

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
```

**Service account**

I was unaware that service account would work with javascript its awesome you got that working.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the calendar itself?  can you do anything with that service account and javascript?  i really didnt think service accounts would work in a client sided language.

Comment: @DalmTo I can authorize my web token fine, I can try my primary calendar, what credentials should I use? I have updated my original question